# using form_for without a model or changeset

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to create a form that just has a text field and a hidden field that I'm going to use when passing data to an HTTP API, so I don't have a model associated with it, and by extension, no changeset.

Is it possible to do this and use `form_for` or is the answer to just write HTML to create the form?

Comment: Hi, Spike!  Stumbled on this just snoopin around Phoenix questions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [form_for/4](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#form_for/4) passing a `Plug.Conn` as the first argument.

From [the docs](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html) (specifically the "With connection data" section):

> form_for/4 expects as first argument any data structure that implements the Phoenix.HTML.FormData protocol. [By default, Phoenix implements this protocol for Plug.Conn](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/v2.3.1/lib/phoenix_html/form_data.ex#L44), allowing us to create forms based only on connection information.
>
> This is useful when you are creating forms that are not backed by any kind of model data, like a search form.

```
<%= form_for @conn, search_path(@conn, :new), [as: :search], fn f -> %>
  <%= text_input f, :for %>
  <%= submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I skimmed that page this morning, but didn't notice that section. This is awesome.

Comment: The `name` keyword is deprecated and the new keyword is `as` in `form_for`.